# Creating a border on a tile?

Tags: sprites, tilemap, grid, godot, pixel

I'm using Godot and I want to set an outline on the tile which is currently being hovered over, but I'm not sure whether to do it as a seperate tilemap which is hidden until it is hovered over or just display a highlighted tile sprite when the tile is hovered.

This is an example of how I sorta want it.
[image]

Any advice?

Comment: It sounds like you have two potential solutions already. Which have you tried implementing so far? Are you unsatisfied with a particular aspect of how that solution is working for you?

Comment: @DMGregory It's more I was after maybe an easy method (if there is one). As it seems like a thing many games implement, so users can see where they're clicking.

Comment: What in particular about your current proposals is not as easy as you'd like? Bear in mind that many things that are common in games are actually quite hard — we just buckle down and do them anyway — so I'd recommend that you just try one of your solutions to see if it works and you can keep building the rest of your game, rather than waiting for a better alternative that might or might not exist.